# My newwindow won't run

Tags: javascript, php

Here is my function:

```
function swipe2(no) {
 window.open ( 'edit.php?no='+no,'newwindow')
}
```

and my php code:

```
echo ("<td>
    <img src='edit.jpg' width='20' alt='Edit' title='EDIT DATA' 
        onClick=\"swipe2('". mysql_result($result, $i, 'no') ."');
       style='cursor:pointer;'>
</td>");
```

Problem is, cursor pointers won't show and none of my functions will run.

Comment: How does a rendered `<td>...</td>` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quotes are not properly ended:

```
echo ("<td>
    <img src='edit.jpg' width='20' alt='Edit' title='EDIT DATA' 
    onClick=\"swipe2('". mysql_result($result, $i, 'no') ."');\"
   style='cursor:pointer;'>
</td>");
```

Answer (score 0):

It helps you!

```
    echo "<td> <img src='edit.jpg' width='20' alt='Edit' title='EDIT DATA'     onClick=\"swipe2('". mysql_result($result, $i, 'no') ."');\" style='cursor:pointer;'>&nbsp;</td>";
```